# issues calling another class

Tags: c#, class

first class as follows:

```
public class employeeApp
{
    public static void main()
    {
        EmployeeProgram.employee Employee = new EmployeeProgram.employee( );
    }

    public void employee(int employeeNumber, string name, string dateOfHire, int monthlySalary)
    {
        employeeNumber = 123;
        name = Cody;
        dateOfHire = 01/01/11;
        monthlySalary = 2500;
    }
}
```

second class as follows:

```
/*
 * Mosbrucker_C_PRO_01              Author: Mosbrucker, Cody
 * Creates a class for employee with data members;
 * Employee number, name, date of hire, and monthly salary.
 * ****************************************************/

public class employee
{
      private int employeeNumber;
      private string name;
      private string dateOfHire;
      private int monthlySalary;


    public int EmployeeNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public string DateOfHire
    {
        get
        {
            return dateOfHire;
        }
        set
        {
            dateOfHire = value;
        }
    }

    public int MonthlySalary
    {
        get
        {
            return monthlySalary;
        }
        set
        {
            monthlySalary = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Employee Id: " + employeeNumber +
               "Employee Name: " + name +
               "Employee Date of Hire: " + dateOfHire +
               "Employee Monthly Salary: " + monthlySalary;
    }
}
```

the problems I am getting are:
 *In my employeeApp class "does not contain a "static" main method for suitable entry point"
 *in my employeeApp class "the name Cody does not exist in current context
 *in my employeeApp class relating to dateOfHire "cannot implicitly convert int to string

I'm doing this for a class and the assignment it:
Create a Employee class. Items to include as data members are employee number, name, date of hire, and monthly salary. Include appropriate constructors and properties. Override the ToString ( ) method to return all data members. Create a second class to test your Employee class.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.in C# we use Main(Capital M) so Main method should be :

```
static void Main()
```

2.You have to create the Constructor in your class `employe`
3.You have to assign String to the String variable but you are assigning date.
as below :

```
dateOfHire = 01/01/11;
```

in your constructor

4.`Cody` should be represented as String `"Cody"` in your Constructor
5.while assigning data to local variables in class use `this` to represent current object when assigning variable have same name

example : `this.employeenumber=employeenumber;`
file 1:

```
namespace employee
{
public class employeeApp
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        EmployeeProgram.employee Employee = new EmployeeProgram.employee(123,"Cody","11/11/11",24567);//call your constructor

    }
  }
}
```

file 2:

```
/*
 * Mosbrucker_C_PRO_01              Author: Mosbrucker, Cody
 * Creates a class for employee with data members;
 * Employee number, name, date of hire, and monthly salary.
 * ****************************************************/
 namespace EmployeeProgram
 {
   public class employee
    {
      private int employeeNumber;
      private string name;
      private string dateOfHire;
      private int monthlySalary;

       public employee(int employeeNumber, string name, string dateOfHire, int monthlySalary)
    {

        this.employeeNumber = 123;
        this.name = "Cody";
        this.dateOfHire = "01/01/11";
        this.monthlySalary = 2500;
    }

    public int EmployeeNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public string DateOfHire
    {
        get
        {
            return dateOfHire;
        }
        set
        {
            dateOfHire = value;
        }
    }

    public int MonthlySalary
    {
        get
        {
            return monthlySalary;
        }
        set
        {
            monthlySalary = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Employee Id: " + employeeNumber +
               "Employee Name: " + name +
               "Employee Date of Hire: " + dateOfHire +
               "Employee Monthly Salary: " + monthlySalary;
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1 -** C# is case sensitive.  Capitalize Main.  The use of the `public` access modifier is not necessary and is generally not recommended for `Main`.

`static void Main()`

**Issue 2 -** For the second `name = Cody;` I guess you meant...`name = "Cody";`

**Issue 3 -** For the third issue you need to convert the int values to string by calling `ToString()` on int values.   `employeeNumber.ToString()` and `monthlySalary.ToString()`.

There are lots of issues here and they are all fairly basic.  I recommend you use Google or explain why exactly you could not solve them.  Otherwise it might appear you have not put forth the required effort to solve the problems yourself.

**Issue 4** As for the I/O write problem you need to qualify using `this` keyword because of the naming conflict between your local variables and private fields:

```
public class employee
{
    private int employeeNumber;
    private string name;
    private string dateOfHire;
    private int monthlySalary;

    public employee(int employeeNumber, string name, string dateOfHire, int monthlySalary)
    {
        this.employeeNumber = 123;//because you have naming collissions you need to use `this`
        this.name = "Cody";
        this.dateOfHire = "01 / 01 / 11";
        this.monthlySalary = 2500;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Employee Id: " + employeeNumber +
               "Employee Name: " + name +
               "Employee Date of Hire: " + dateOfHire +
               "Employee Monthly Salary: " + monthlySalary;
    }


    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then Main

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        employee e = new employee(1,"","",0);//these values are ignored the way you set this up
        e.Print();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I think he use main() instead of Main() is because he don't want to clash the entry point at his main program

Comment: If there were an entry point then he would not have received the indicated error `does not contain a "static" main method for suitable entry point`

Comment: yea, that was the big issue that i just simply overlooked, i've gotten most things fixed thanks to everyone's help. now my only issue is i'm not sure why when i run it, it displays my strings as blank and my ints as 0. im assuming i did not call them correctly?

Comment: @user2994740 Please post the code you are using to display them.

Comment: if you want to assign values you should call as below:  EmployeeProgram.employee Employee = new EmployeeProgram.employee(1,"Cody","11/11/2010",23400);

Comment: @Sudhakar ~ i received an error saying that i dont have a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Comment: @MosbruckerCJ : did you change your code as per my post? you have to add constructor in employee class see my answer

Comment: yep, and at  public void employee(int employeeNumber, string name, string dateOfHire, int monthlySalary)
    {

        this.employeeNumber = 123;
        this.name = "Cody";
        this.dateOfHire = "01/01/11";
        this.monthlySalary = 2500;
    }


i get an error : member names cannot be the same as enclosing type

Comment: and i did assign the variables in EmployeeProgram.employe Employee = new EmployeeProgramemployee

Comment: @MosbruckerCJ: see my edited answer "call your constructor statement"

Comment: @MosbruckerCJ: remove void in public void employee(int employeeNumber, string name, string dateOfHire, int monthlySalary); it should be public employee(int employeeNumber, string name, string dateOfHire, int monthlySalary)

Comment: @MosbruckerCJ: see my edited answer with new constructor in file2 , it works perfectly.

Comment: @MosbruckerCJ - Note naming conflict.  Question updated.  In the future please ask 1 question per post.  This 1 question needed 4 answers.  That is not fair to those having to answer 4 questions and get credit for 1.

Comment: @p.Brian.Mackey im sorry, i did not know that was how it worked, i will definitely keep that in mind for in the future, thank you again

Comment: @MosbruckerCJ Not a problem.  I understand you are new to the site.  Welcome to Stack Overflow and glad to have you!